# Is a certified copy of my marriage certificate sufficient proof of name change when traveling to the US?

Tags: usa, air-travel, paperwork

I have a USA visitor's visa in my maiden surname. My new passport displays my married surname. I do not have my original marriage certificate with me but I do have a certified copy. Will this be sufficient proof of name change/ will they accept a certified copy?

Comment: Doesn't your new (or old) passport have an annotation in it that says something about a name change? In some countries with a name change the old passport is cancelled and a note added on the last page indicating it was cancelled because a new passport has been issued in a different/married name.

Comment: No unfortunately there is not an annotation. That would have been even better.

Answer (score 4):

**No, it is not enough**.

I have no idea why someone has not answered such a simple question yet.

**You can no longer use that visa after your name change**, even if you carry the original marriage certificate with you.

> **I changed my name. Is my U.S. visa with my old name still valid?**
>
> If your name has legally changed through marriage, divorce, or a court ordered name change, you will need to obtain a new passport.  Once you have a new passport, the Department of State recommends that you apply for a new U.S. visa to make it easier for you to travel to and from the United States.

[U.S. Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/about-basics.html)

Also read this excellent Q & A on [state.gov/libraries](https://photos.state.gov/libraries/port-of-spain/223848/consular/Ask%20the%20Consul%202010%2010%2004%20v2.pdf).

Comment: "the Department of State recommends" implies that the old visa _is_ valid.  If the old visa were invalid, they would say "Once you have a new passport, you must obtain a new visa to travel to the United States."